# Not able to upload mutiple files to local directory using multer file in node and angular2

Tags: node.js, angular2-routing

I have a requirement where I want to upload multiple images in `node.js`. so I am using  `angular2` for frontend. I am using formData to send the files to node part.
below is the code :

```
public setAnswerImage(obj:any,files:any):Promise<any> {
        try {
          let urlDetails = obj["id"] ? ANSWER_URLS['updateimages'] : ANSWER_URLS['insertimages'];
          let formData = new FormData();

          Object.keys(obj).forEach(key =>{
              formData.append(key,obj[key]);
          }); 
         console.log(formData)
          for(let i =0; i < files.length; i++){
            formData.append("uploads[]", files[i],files[i]['name']);
        }
          console.log(formData)
          return this.restUtils.post(urlDetails, formData, {"id":obj["id"]});
        }
        catch(err) {
          return Promise.reject(err);  
        }
      }


let urlDetails = obj["id"] ? ANSWER_URLS['updateimages'] : ANSWER_URLS['insertimages'];
```

If obj contains id I will be calling update method else insert method.

```
export const ANSWER_URLS = {
 insertimages : { url : "/api/answer/response/insertimages"}
}
```

In Node part I am using multer file storage, i have created a folder as temp and path has been set to this folder in multer as shown below.

```
router.post("/response/insertimages", upload.array("uploads[]", 12), (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      new AnswerRoute().saveAnswerImages(req, res, next);
    });

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req: Request, file, cb) => {
       cb(null, video_path.dest + 'temp//');
      }, filename: (req:Request, file, cb) => {

          let name = file.originalname.split('.');
          console.log(name,"mnae")
        cb(null, new Date().getTime().toString() + '.' + name[name.length-1]);
    }

    })

    var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

`Console.log` output shows multiple files I uploaded but in temp folder, I can see only one :

```
[ 'doctor', 'jpg' ] 'mnae'
[ 'Doctorvisits', 'png' ] 'mnae'
```

The above output shows two images I uploaded but only one file is saved in the temp folder.

I am using `upload.array("uploads[]",12)`, where uploads contain multiple files but the problem is when I upload multiple files only first file gets uploaded to the temp folder.

Am I going wrong somewhere?

Please help me

Comment: I think as maybe `new Date().getTime().toString()` returns same for the two files. So can you change the filename? like `name[0] + new Date().getTime().toString() + '.' + name[name.length-1]` and see what happens?